# Location to add view files: SPRING MVC

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-mvc

In SPRING MVC project, Which is the right folder location to create a new JSP(view) file:

WebContent\new_jsp_file.jsp

or

Java Resources\src\com.example.view\new_jsp_file.jsp

Note: com.example.view is a manually created package

Answer (score 0):

Usually JSP file is located here:

```
%projectfolder%/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

`JSP` files should be put inside `WEB-INF` directory, because contents of `WEB-INF` aren't *directly* accessible by users, which is needed for application security.

If you are using `Maven` or `Gradle`:

```
project-name
|- src
  |- main
    |- java
    |- resources
    |- webapp
      |- WEB-INF 
        |--- put JSPs here, can create subdirectories if needed
```